# Android Studio 2.3 でエミュレータが起動しない

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

Android Studio 2.3 へアップデートしたところエミュレータが起動しなくなりました。

> Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Android Studio 2.2.3 のときは問題なく AVD は起動できました

OS は Ubuntu 16.04 です

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

取り敢えず自己解決しました

解決方法は長くなるので下記のブログに記述しました

[Android Studio 2.3 AVDが起動しない for Ubuntu 16.04](http://ameblo.jp/juhr9/entry-12256871870.html)